# Does PhpStorm have built-in git revisions graph?

Tags: git, phpstorm

On [PhpStorm's homepage](https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/) is an image showing git revisions and branches graph:

[image]

No matter how much I try I can't find it. How to turn it on?

Talking about PhpStorm 8.0.3 on Linux.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are several ways of opening it.

1. Press <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>9</kbd> and then go to "Log" tab.
2. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> and then type `changes`. Or at the bottom of PHPStorm you might find tab named `Changes`.
3. Go to `VCS` menu at the top and then select `Show Changes view`